# Click on an element on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an autotest in python and selenium
There is such an element on the page. How to specify it in the code so that the click will work?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNLQ.png)

Tried this option but it didn't help:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Не отправлены') and @onclick='getDiv('wait_block', this)']").click()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.